# Match a regular expression, then remove a subset of that regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript to parse through some strings.

I have some strings that look like this:

```
1234 1/2 Old Town Alexandria
```

I have written a regular expression to identify instances in which a fraction comes after the street number:

```
var addressFractionRegex = /^\d*\s+(1[/]\d)\s+/i;
```

What I would like to do is remove the fraction part of the regular expression from the source string only in cases where the entire regular expression is matched (ie: the fraction is preceded by a street number).  In this case, I would end up with (removing the "1/2"):

```
1234 Old Town Alexandria
```

I would also like to save the part that I removed into another variable.  So ideally, I'd end up with something like:

```
var street_address = '1234 Old Town Alexandria';
var fraction = '1/2';
```

How is this done in javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**replace can take a function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
var fraction;
var street_address = "1234 1/2 Old Town Alexandria".replace(/^\d*\s+(1[/]\d)\s+/i, function (match, capture) {
    fraction = capture.trim();
    return match.replace(capture,'')
});

fraction; // 1/2
street_address; // 1234 Old Town Alexndria
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YsNpg/)

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` function takes a replacement string.  You can group everything you want to keep, and omit anything you want to take out. Here we keep subpatterns 1 and 3, and leave out your fraction stored in 2.

```
var addressFractionRegex = /^(\d*\s+)(1[/]\d)(\s+)/i;

var data = '123 1/5 abc';

alert(data.replace(addressFractionRegex, '$1$3'));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPHmE/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could capture only the bit you want to keep:

```
"1234 1/2 Old Town Alexandria".replace(/^(\d*\s+)1\/\d\s/, '$1');
```